# Running Play Framework 2.0 in Windows, got a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: windows, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to run Play Framework 2.0 in windows (XP), but when I launch play, I got this exception :

```
>play.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: and.  Program will exit.
```

I can't find why I have this error. Of course I have Java installed :

```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And javac :

```
>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_31
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, for those who have the same problem, it's quite simple in fact.

I was running Play in "My Documents" and the whole path contained space.

In order for Play! to work, you'll have to put your project in a folder without spaces, like :

> C:\dev\play\2.0\

And it will work :)

Comment: I suggest you create a ticket for this on https://play.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard