# Playframework 2.0 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have used play framework to develop a Web Application. Through the process of development I always used "play run" to start the server.

Today I tried to start the server for deployment by running "play start" and then I got error as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

I believe it's a "space in path" because the "missing class"  name "Files" reminds my about "Program Files". But my play was installed to a directory with no space. Also, I was able to run "play run" all the time.

Are there any other place should I look for?

UPDATE: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305131/running-play-framework-2-0-in-windows-got-a-noclassdeffounderror) but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the project's as well as play's path doesn't contain any spaces?

Comment: Does your JAVA_HOME env variable contains space ? if so, put some quotes around the path.

Comment: @Li-o Yes, I am sure there is no space in both of the paths.

Comment: @nico_ekito, I checked my environment variables. I do not have a JAVA_HOME variable. I will try windows registry.

Comment: @WeiMa And your CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: I had quotations around the classpath variable

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue using 2.0.3 issuing the "play start" command. Under 2.0.4 I'm still getting the issue with play start, but running

```
play run
```

works like a charm.

Comment: Do you really want to `run` your app in production? Isn't it waste of resources ?