# Playframework: Strange behavior of "play start" - Caching issue?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am currently developing a web app using play framework 2. I have created a folder "files" under /public directory. All the resources under that directory were accessible when I start the server using "play run".

After deploy to the server. I started the server by running "play start" and found the resources under "files" cannot be found anymore.

I am wondering what is the cause of the inconsistency between "play start" and "play run"

UPDATE:After a few trial. I found that it's the newly uploaded resource cannot be shown. The scenario is the following:

```
1. play start --> server starts.
2. use application to upload a few images to the server.
3. try to display the uploaded image --> nothing is shown. browser shows the resource is not accessible.
4. kill the server process with task manager.
5. rm RUNNING_PID
6. run play start again 
7. Try to display the uploaded image --> now the images are showing.
```

So, looks like a "hot update" issue with "play start"
Is there any configuration I can do to let the server pick up the change?
Thanks.

Comment: Already test in your local `play start`? If there is stack trace please add to your post.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to run "play start" on my local machine because of an error I described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713173/playframework-2-0-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where exactly did you store the image?
At compile time, the static assets are copied from `/public` to `/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/public`. This directory is part of the class path and the assets are served from there. So, if you store files there at runtime, they should be found.

Side note: It is probably not a sustainable solution since images loaded up by your users are removed during the next build. Maybe you should consider using a symbolic link outside your app installation (attention! security issue!) or store the assets somewhere else, the database or S3 always being good alternatives.

Comment: I am putting the images under /public/files directory. So, you are saying when a user put the path /assets/files/xxx.jpg in the url, the server will look for /target/scala-2.9.1/classes/public/files to look for this file? If so, I could create my image at both places when user uploads. But why playframework was designed in such way? Isn't serving static resource one of the common scenarios?

Comment: @wei-ma: It is of course, but **static** resources are not meant to be changed on runtime... Therefore the are compiled, optionally gzipped, at compile time. As I proposed: Put the uploaded file somewhere else on disk and write your own simple controller, serving this file on request.

Comment: Guess I am too used to the way IIS behaves. By default, IIS serves static contents as is, no caching, no compressing. I am wondering if I can configure play to do the same. I believe implementing a simple controller won't be too hard, but shouldn't the framework give me the choice of not having these extra functionality?

Comment: I'll mark you answer as the accepted one. But I also provided how I eventually solved this problem below.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Joerg Viola 's answer. I decided to implement my own action to serve static resource. Turns out it's extremely easy. From [`this link`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaStream) , I learnt to implement a file server in one line.